# php activerecord ORDER BY causes query to fail

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project that uses php active record.  there are 3 tables (users,punches,and jobs)  When I run this query

```
$records = Punches::find_by_sql("Select * from jobs,users,punches where jobs.job_id = $job_id AND punches.job_id = $job_id AND punches.id= users.id AND NOT ISNULL(end_time) ORDER BY last_name,id ");
```

the query fails.  If I take the order by out it works just fine.  Please note I've used every variation of ORDER BY I can think of.

Comment: forget DESC or ASC..?

Comment: is this query runs in phpmyadmin? What is the error?

Comment: just a guess but do more than one table share the column name `id` or last_name?

Comment: You need to mention which table you're referring to in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Special thanks to whoever suggested I run it in phpmyadmin... made fixing it easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be spesific for `id` in your `order by id`, because `users` and `punches` tables have id too

```
$records = Punches::find_by_sql("... ORDER BY last_name, TABLENAME.id");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are joining multiple tables, you need to specify which tables columns you are using when the column is not unique. In your case you need to specify which table the id column is from.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to whoever suggested that I run it in phpmyadmin... that helped to spot the error quickly.  I needed tablename.id